# Calculating decimals

Tags: c#, decimal

I managed to calculate variables but my question is how do I calculate numbers with decimals?

```
int Var1;
int Var2;
int Uitkomst;

Var1 = Convert.ToInt16(txtGetal1.Text);
Var2 = Convert.ToInt16(txtGetal2.Text);

Uitkomst = Var1 * Var2;

txtUitkomst.Text = "Uitkomst:" + Uitkomst.ToString();
```

Comment: [decimal.TryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal.tryparse?view=net-5.0)

Comment: and `int` isn't a `decimal`, they are different types

Comment: " if I try calculating decimals." then you should post the code with the decimals. we cannot help you with working code

Comment: FYI an `int` is an `Int32`. `Int16` is a 16-bit `short`. See [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/integral-numeric-types)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should declare your `Var1` and `Var2` and you may use `double.Parse()` to convert the user input

I changed your code into this:

```
double Var1;
double Var2;
double Uitkomst;

Var1 = double.Parse(txtGetal1.Text);
Var2 = double.Parse(txtGetal2.Text);

Uitkomst = Var1 * Var2;

txtUitkomst.Text = "Uitkomst:" + Uitkomst.ToString();
```